# Left join isn't working when I am selecting count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join a company and their details, as well as transactions even if they don't exist.

I am counting the transactions to guage how many users are going to a course, if there's no transactions I still want to join the company and details, but the count would be 0, in my query below the training_company table is being selected, but the training_details is not being selected for some reason:

```
SELECT training.*, count(distinct training_transactions.training_transaction_course) as completed_training_payments 
 FROM training
LEFT JOIN training_company
    ON training.course_main = training_company_id
LEFT JOIN training_details
    ON training.course_main = training_details_company
LEFT JOIN training_transactions
    ON training.course_user = training_transactions.training_transaction_user
WHERE course_id = ?
        AND       training_transactions.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
        AND       training_transactions.training_transaction_payment_status = 'complete'
        AND course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

training_company:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_company` (
  `training_company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_company_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_company_enabled` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `training_company_has_avatar` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `training_company_has_banner` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `training_company`
--

INSERT INTO `training_company` (`training_company_id`, `training_company_name`, `training_company_user`, `training_company_enabled`, `training_company_has_avatar`, `training_company_has_banner`) VALUES
(1, '123', 1, 'enabled', 0, 0),
```

training_details:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_details` (
  `training_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_registration_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_street` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_town` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_county` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_postcode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_street` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_town` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_county` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_postcode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_company_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_total_employees` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_fax` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_landline` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_mobile` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `training_details_website` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `company_differs_address` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `training_details`
--

INSERT INTO `training_details` (`training_details_id`, `training_details_user`, `training_details_company`, `training_details_registration_number`, `training_details_type`, `training_details_name`, `training_details_street`, `training_details_town`, `training_details_county`, `training_details_postcode`, `training_details_country`, `training_details_company_name`, `training_details_company_street`, `training_details_company_town`, `training_details_company_county`, `training_details_company_postcode`, `training_details_company_country`, `training_details_total_employees`, `training_details_fax`, `training_details_landline`, `training_details_mobile`, `training_details_email`, `training_details_website`, `company_differs_address`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, '0', '', '123', '123', '123', '123456', 'WN8', 'Australia', '123', '123', '123', '', 'WN8', 'Australia', '', '', '', '', '', '', 4),
```

training:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_description` text NOT NULL,
  `course_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_fitness_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_instructor_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_price` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `course_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `course_max_attendees` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `course_enabled` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `course_location_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_county` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_certificate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `course_certificate_valid` int(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `training`
--

INSERT INTO `training` (`course_id`, `course_user`, `course_main`, `course_type`, `course_name`, `course_description`, `course_location`, `course_duration`, `course_fitness_type`, `course_instructor_name`, `course_price`, `course_start_date`, `course_max_attendees`, `course_accommodation`, `course_accommodation_price`, `course_status`, `course_enabled`, `course_location_name`, `course_location_street`, `course_location_town`, `course_location_county`, `course_location_postcode`, `course_location_country`, `course_certificate`, `course_certificate_valid`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 'Hazardous', '123', 'dddddddddddddd', 'other', '14', 'lol', 'lol', 123, '2015-11-09', 4, '0', '', 'pending', 'enabled', '123', '123', '123', '123456', '123', 'Australia', '123', 2),
```

So how can I get my join to work on details, because at the moment it is not joining even though everything matches

Comment: The `left join` works fine.  You need to move the conditions from the `where` clauses to the `on` clauses.  Frankly, I find it really, really difficult to follow queries that mix `left join` and `right join`, but you should understand the query so you should be able to figure out which conditions go where.

Comment: Your prose suggests that you want a right join to company, not left.

Comment: I've tried adding it to the on with no look and right join :(

Comment: @randommman Creating a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) might get your question some more attention.

Comment: `training_transactions` schema and datasample missed

Comment: isn't this a question for dba stack?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: provide schema and sample data for transaction table

Comment: it is better to create SQLFiddle rather than posting here... anyone can quickly answer your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff suggested in the first comment, move the conditions involving the `training_transactions` from the `WHERE` clause into the `LEFT JOIN`.

Of course, you should also list the columns explicitly instead of `*` and add a corresponding `GROUP BY` for the `COUNT` to work.

```
SELECT 
    training.course_id
    ,training.course_user
    ...
    ,count(distinct training_transactions.training_transaction_course) as completed_training_payments 
FROM
    training
    LEFT JOIN training_company ON training.course_main = training_company_id
    LEFT JOIN training_details ON training.course_main = training_details_company
    LEFT JOIN training_transactions
        ON  training_transactions.training_transaction_user = training.course_user
        AND training_transactions.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
        AND training_transactions.training_transaction_payment_status = 'complete'
WHERE
    training.course_id = ?
    AND training.course_enabled = 'enabled'
GROUP BY
    training.course_id
    ,training.course_user
    ...
```

There are also few things that you should pay attention to in this query.

```
WHERE
    course_id = ?
    AND course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

It is not clear for a new person reading the query (as everybody reading this question and the next person who will be maintaining your code, which could be you in two years time) what table these fields belong to. Always try to indicate the table explicitly, like this:

```
WHERE
    training.course_id = ?
    AND training.course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

It also helps to use aliases.

In the similar fashion, it is not clear what is going on in the `JOIN`:

```
    LEFT JOIN training_company ON training.course_main = training_company_id
    LEFT JOIN training_details ON training.course_main = training_details_company
```

Is it just an oversight when simplifying the query for this question, or this is your real code? In any case, include the table name (or alias).

```
LEFT JOIN training_company ON training.course_main = training_company.training_company_id
LEFT JOIN training_details ON training.course_main = training_details.training_details_company
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going a different route altogether and not use left joins.  Since you want all data from the training table and you want an aggregate (count in your case) from  a different table, I would suggest breaking the aggregate out into a separate subquery.  Here's what I mean (note I added aliases to your tables to simplify things as well):

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT count(distinct tt.training_transaction_course)
          FROM training_company tc        
          JOIN training_details td ON td.course_main = tc.training_details_company
          JOIN training_transactions tt ON t.course_user = tt.training_transaction_user
         WHERE t.course_main = tc.training_company_id
           AND tt.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
           AND tt.training_transaction_payment_status = 'complete')
        as completed_training_payments 
 FROM training t
WHERE t.course_id = ?
  AND t.course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

This will guarantee a row returned for every row in the training table that matches the entered course_id.  Also, if the subquery returns no rows then it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this. To begin with it is difficult to reproduce without the schema for `training_transactions`.

Further it would appear from your description and schema that you want an inner join on the first table. `training` would always have a company, if I read this right. `training_details` appear to be irrelevant to the query and would give a cross product if it they weren't so leave that out entirely.

I am assuming joining to transactions by user is wrong since you have a training_transaction_course which I assume is the correct foreign key.

The count is just wrong - that's not how it works and you do need a GROUP BY clause if you want the count.

The WHERE clause appears right to me since the elements are not used in any join.

This would give you something like this:

```
SELECT training.course_id, -- everything you put here needs to go in the group by clause
    count(training_transactions.training_transaction_course) as completed_training_payments
   FROM training
   JOIN training_company
       ON training.course_main = training_company_id
   LEFT JOIN training_transactions
       ON training.course_id = training_transactions.training_transaction_course
   WHERE course_id = ?
       AND training_transactions.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
       AND training_transactions.training_transaction_payment_status = 'complete'
       AND course_enabled = 'enabled'
   GROUP BY training.course_id, training_transactions.training_transaction_course
```

~

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query will **never** result in more than one row.

Use Groupby or nested queries as said in other answers.